# Can we create platform event dynamically without using UI?

Tags: apex, trigger, streaming-api, platform-event, webhooks

I want to create a platform event dynamically using any programming language. But I didn't find any API. Can you please tell me I can make platform event dynamically?

Comment: When you say you want to create - do you mean that you want to create a platform event record or you want to create the platform event object/fields altogether?

Comment: new platform object so to listen on that.

Comment: Why would you need to create the metadata dynamically? What is your use case? Seems you just want to create the object first in Salesforce and then subscribe to it.

Comment: actually i want to make a connector for various organisation. We have partner with salesforce also.

Answer (score 1):

Platform events are migrated the same as normal Custom Objects. See [Migrate Platform Event Definitions with Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_metadata_api.htm) for specific details. Basically, you use the Metadata API, and you retrieve and deploy them the same as other CustomObject metadata objects, which also includes Custom Settings.

Comment: i'm new to it. Migration meaning we define a code and dynamically define platform event using java code also?

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar Yes, you can do so with the Metadata API.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you tell me how to use with metadata API?

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar It's all in the documentation. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I try to create platform event using meta data api. But I don't know how to use. I am good in REST API. But  I never seen these type of API to work with java.